# extract dynamic session id from a from wildcard domain using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a user member system which uses a protection such that a session id is generated for every user which is our member and with the help of wildcard domain the session id is used in urls . suppose rty100.example.com . What i need is to extract the `rty100` from link . since the session id will change everytime so it will be dynamic but the `.example.com` will be same everytime . Is there a good and fast way to achieve that? Also how will i detect if there is some session id present or not as if not the link would be `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery, you could use the variable `window.location.host` and split it into an array to find a link's subdomain. Using the URL `rty100.example.com` as an example;

```
var url = window.location.host;
var parts = url.split('.');

parts[0] //rty100
parts[1] //example
parts[2] //com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.location.host.split('.')[0];
```

That gives you the bit that is before `.example.com`.